# How to convert yyyy-mm-ddthh:mm:ss.sssz on laravel api or flutter view?

Tags: php, flutter, datetime, laravel-8, flutter-android

I build android apps using flutter and laravel rest api.
but I get start_time with this format (yyyy-mm-ddthh:mm:ss.sssz) on `postman`:
[image]

on database `sql server` it looks fine:

[image]

my `flutter` apps view:
[image]

Can some one help me to convert starttime data? this make a wrong time output. I've tried to change model on laravel like this. but it make error '500' when user input data.
[image]

Comment: Standard Laravel will always work with Livewire. I don't understand what you're trying to do though, because your question is unclear and you're not showing any related code

Comment: @Qirel I've edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can try this on your flutter :

```
final starttime = DateTime.parse(cutiData['start_time']).toLocal();
final endtime = DateTime.parse(cutiData['end_time']).toLocal();
```

ANd you call in return as string:

```
starttime.toString(),
endtime.toString(),
```